# Is there a racket equivalent of 'python -i filename.py'?

Tags: scheme, racket, read-eval-print-loop

When I develop python, I often use `python -i filename.py` to run the file, and then go into interactive mode in the namespace of the given file, so e.g. if I had defined `C=3`, I could then access it from the prompt as

```
>>> C
3
```

I'm trying to find a way to use the `racket` command line program in a similar way, but the closest I've gotten is

```
$ racket -i -e "(require \"filename.rkt\")"
> C
3
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out

```
racket -it filename.rkt
> C
3
```

or

```
racket -iu filename.rkt
> C
3
```

Not really sure what the differences are, but the command line help says the following

```
-t <file>, --require <file> : Like -e '(require (file "<file>"))' [*]
-u <file>, --require-script <file> : Same as -t <file> -N <file> --
-N <file>, --name <file> : Sets `(find-system-path 'run-file)' to <file>
```